# opening pdf using ashx (handler) file

Tags: .net

This is the handler code: If I navigate directly to this handler it shows pdf fine. On Aspx page I have a image control, pdf doesn't show in imagecontrol. Accroding to all google search this is supposed to be shown in image control

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

            WebClient imageWebClient = new WebClient();
            byte[] imageBytes = imageWebClient.DownloadData(Testlocation);
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            //context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=image.pdf");
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", imageBytes.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes);
            context.Response.Flush();
```

}

Markup on Aspx page:

Comment: You're talking about an image control - I can't see anywhere in the docs which specifies it can show a pdf

Answer (score 3):

> Accroding to all google search this is supposed to be shown in image control

No idea what searches you are referring to but image controls are supposed to display images, not PDFs. Image controls render as `<img>` tags in the HTML. `<img>` tags can only be used with images. If you want to embed a PDF inside a page you could use an `<iframe>` pointing its `src` property to your ashx handler.

Comment: @user228777, is there something else you would like to ask?